# open64() fails with ENOENT, even though the file exists

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to open a file that I just created with open64(). When I try to open the file though, the syscall fails with ENOENT. I know for a fact the file exists, because I just created it and ls shows it in the directory it is supposed to be in. When I try to open it with open(), it fails with EOVERFLOW, which is expected, but it also implies the file exists. Any ideas?

```
const char* filename = pDt->evtfname;
int evtFile;
evtFile = open64(filename, O_RDONLY); 
perror("The following error occurred");
```

Comment: Are you sure filename references the path to the file, and not just the filename without the directory to it ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have used gdb to verify.

Comment: When you attempt to open the file with `open()` and with `open64()`, is the filename exactly the same each time?

Comment: Yes it is. (junk for char limit)

Comment: This is a side issue, but you should never write `open64`. Compile your program with the proper compilation environment for 64-bit `off_t`. On Linux this means using `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` in your `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Is it just a matter of convention? Or is there a programmatic difference? I ask because there is open64 calls elsewhere in the codebase in parts that I didn't write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's evtFile value? You do not check it. errno is valid only if evtFile < 0

Comment: Great scott. It's 7. Thanks for the help. I guess I was under the impression errno was reset every syscall if successful.